# Visual Studio 2017 - SDK and AVD wont open

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, sdk, android-virtual-device

So i have installed Visual Studio 2017 Community version for my windows 7 laptop. The installation completed with an error log that said that it had failed to download the Android Emulator for it.

Now, when i try to click on The AVD Manager or the SDK - both do nothing at all (no feedback too).

When i try to do a repair or modify - VS will tell "Setup Operation Failed".

I have search online for the Android Emulator only package - but all found were compatible with windows 8 or more.

I have looked online, and some people still have this problem - but no solution.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Error log bit:

```
The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.

Incomplete workloads
    Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26403.0)

Incomplete components
    Android NDK (R13B) (Component.Android.NDK.R13B,version=13.1.6)
    Android SDK setup (API level 23) (Component.Android.SDK23,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Google Android Emulator (API Level 23) (Component.Google.Android.Emulator.API23.V2,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) (Component.HAXM,version=15.0.26208.0)
```

Comment: Where is you Android SDK location? You can find your Android SDK location in Visual Studio Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Setting->Android SDK Location, its default location is C:\Program File(86)\Android\android-sdk. Have yo change this location?

Answer (score 0):

Google recently released Android SDK Tools 26.0.1(March 2017) that comes with the Android Studio 2.3.1(April 2017) update. This version of Android SDK Tools deprecates the `android` program in the `tools` folder.

Because of this deprecation, the SDK Manager and AVD Manager stand-alone programs will no longer work when invoking them from the respective IDE menus. Rather Google has recommended that users now use the CLI tooling.

[LINK](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=54521)